# Findstr does not return second line

Tags: windows, command-line, findstr

I am using `FINDSTR` -I to find a string in n number of files in a folder. Also write the results to a new file.

I need find string "IDC" along with number next to it in all files.
but on some lines in files, IDC is spread across two lines, and my search returns just first line.

```
09:49:34.386 4;**IDC-200.0**;CA
13:07:39.987 87;T22.8,BT2;LI;VLT12.7;**IDC-**
13:07:39.995 **42.0**;CAP240.0/
```

can some one help in copy next line to output file, if IDC is spread across two lines.

Comment: In your example, you want to extract `200.0` and `42.0`, right? are the `**` always positioned around `IDC-` and the numbers?

Comment: Is the order of numbers as they appear in the file important?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft’s [findstr](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) works strictly line based. It is not really possible to search for a string which does not completely exist within a line and get all lines output.

But it is possible to define multiple search strings which are used one after the other on a line before processing next line until either one of the search strings returns a positive match or none of the search strings matches a string on current line.

Example:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"IDC-" /C:"^[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9] \*\*[0-9][0-9.]*\*\*;" *.txt
```

[Findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) (SS64 article) searches with those options in all `*.txt` files of current folder for

- a line containing case sensitive the string `IDC-` anywhere within the line or
- a line starting with time in expected format, a space, two asterisks, a floating point number with at least 1 digit before decimal point, two more asterisks and a semicolon.

With those two search strings all 3 lines of provided example are found and output in correct order and other lines not containing `IDC-` or matching the second regular expression search string are ignored by **FINDSTR**.

Note: SS64 article [FINDSTR - Searching across Line Breaks](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr-linebreaks.html) explains how a search can be done which includes a line break. But output is nevertheless only the first line on which the found multi-line string begins.